# How to load drawable lazily from xml resource? Resource id only at first not the whole drawable image

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using NetworkImageView of [volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)

I want to set drawable image resource id and error drawable resource id on NetworkImageView of xml resource.
So, I modified the source code, and it works.

**java**

```
    public NetworkImageView(Context context,
    ...
         final TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.NetworkImageView, defStyle, 0);
    mDefaultDrawable = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.NetworkImageView_defaultImage);
    mErrorDrawable = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.NetworkImageView_errorImage);
```

**xml**

```
<...NetworkImageView
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/..."
    custom:resultScaleType="centerCrop"
    custom:errorImage="@drawable/no_image_icon"
    custom:errorScaleType="centerInside"
    custom:loupeViewId="@id/..."
            ...
/>
```

But, problem is, NetworkImageView is always load default and error drawable for the first time even though they are not required.

I think there are too many wastes when I show many `ImageViews` on a `ListView`.

I want to load the resource when they are needed. So, I want to load resource id only at first.

Both `TypedArray.getResourceId()` and `TypedArray.getInt()` do not work.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you try to use stubView?

Answer (score 0):

from developers:

> A **ViewStub** is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily
>   inflate layout resources at runtime.

Maybe this piece of information can benefit you??

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I think ViewStub can not help me since I need inflate only one ImageView which makes changes either "defaultImage --> resultImage" or "defaultImage --> errorImage".